# How do I downgrade an RPM on a machine without 'yum'?

Tags: rpm

On a machine without yum, I have version 3.2 of a package installed and I have downloaded version 2.4 manually, how do I install the older version?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`rpm -Uvh --oldpackage [filename]`

`--oldpackage` allows you to install older versions, `-U` means "upgrade", but in this case it will just replace the other version. If you use `-i` instead of `-U` you will end up with both versions installed.

Comment: The `vh` arguments are optional here. Only `-U` (or `--upgrade`) and `--oldpackage` are necessary.

Comment: `rpm -U --force [filename]` also allows downgrades

Comment: For kernels `rpm -i --force <package url / filename>` works (since you want to keep multiple versions)

Answer (score 16):

You can also try `yum downgrade packagename`, depending on the version of yum on your system.

Comment: You are correct, but OP  specified "on a machine without yum"  so either yum is broken or missing.

Comment: [At the time of this answer](https://serverfault.com/posts/274310/revisions), "without 'yum'" was not part of the OP's question. Please see the edit history.

Comment: Best leave answer for completeness, and your comment clarifies why.